# Optimising a Self-Full Outer Join

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I am currently performing a Full Join on my table which consists of ~1.4m rows and am in the process of attempting to optimise the query from its current time of ~13s. I'm fairly new to the concept of implementing indexes and haven't been able to create one that has reduced the run time.

```
SELECT 
  s1.playerId, 
  s1.teamPosition, 
  s2.playerId, 
  s2.teamPosition, 
  AVG(s1.win), 
  COUNT(s1.playerId) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      matchId, 
      teamId, 
      playerId, 
      teamPosition, 
      win 
    FROM 
      stats
  ) as s1 FULL 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      matchId, 
      teamId, 
      playerId, 
      teamPosition, 
      win 
    FROM 
      stats
  ) as s2 ON s1.matchId = s2.matchId 
  AND s1.teamId = s2.teamId 
WHERE 
  s1.playerId < s2.playerId 
GROUP BY 
  s1.playerId, 
  s1.teamPosition, 
  s2.playerId, 
  s2.teamPosition
```

**Desired Outcome**:
When I view the below information I would like to know which elements to focus on and understand why not/why that element can be optimised with an index for example. Similarly if the query itself is in-efficient somehow and can be improved. I am using pgSQL v14.

Hopefully the question has sufficient information, can update if not.

**Background of Query**: For each match we want to aggregate how often combinations of players from the *same* team win together, and this needs to be done for each match individually. So we join on the matchid and teamId columns and group by the playerId and teamPosition columns.

**Example of Data (1 Match out of ~1.4m)**:

| matchId | teamid | playerId | teamPosition | win |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| match_0001 | 100 | A | High | 0 |
| match_0001 | 100 | B | Center | 0 |
| match_0001 | 100 | C | Middle | 0 |
| match_0001 | 100 | D | Low | 0 |
| match_0001 | 200 | W | High | 1 |
| match_0001 | 200 | X | Center | 1 |
| match_0001 | 200 | Y | Middle | 1 |
| match_0001 | 200 | Z | Low | 1 |

The full stats table includes an additional 3 columns (which are not used) matchLength, Possession_X, and Possession_Y

Example SQL input:

```
with t (matchId, teamId, playerId, teamPosition, win) as (VALUES 
('match_0001',100,'A','High',0),
('match_0001',100,'B','Center',0),
('match_0001',100,'C','Middle',0),
('match_0001',100,'D','Low',0),
('match_0001',200,'W','High',1),
('match_0001',200,'X','Center',1),
('match_0001',200,'Y','Middle',1),
('match_0001',200,'Z','Low',1)
)
select * from t
```

**Output Query Plan using EXPLAIN ANALYZE no CTE (~14s)**:

```
"Sort  (cost=2231977.32..2233637.88 rows=664225 width=56) (actual time=12618.775..12748.527 rows=119692 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: (count(stats.playerid)) DESC"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 12423kB"
"  ->  Finalize HashAggregate  (cost=2159439.59..2167742.40 rows=664225 width=56) (actual time=12546.726..12714.393 rows=119692 loops=1)"
"        Group Key: stats.playerid, stats.teamposition, stats_1.playerid, stats_1.teamposition"
"        Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49177kB"
"        ->  Gather  (cost=2000025.59..2139512.84 rows=1328450 width=56) (actual time=12314.220..12533.081 rows=279744 loops=1)"
"              Workers Planned: 2"
"              Workers Launched: 2"
"              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=1999025.59..2005667.84 rows=664225 width=56) (actual time=12269.500..12297.564 rows=93248 loops=3)"
"                    Group Key: stats.playerid, stats.teamposition, stats_1.playerid, stats_1.teamposition"
"                    Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49177kB"
"                    Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49177kB"
"                    Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 49177kB"
"                    ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=282414.08..1391404.47 rows=40508075 width=18) (actual time=1816.434..7725.901 rows=9532933 loops=3)"
"                          Hash Cond: (((stats.matchid)::text = (stats_1.matchid)::text) AND (stats.teamid = stats_1.teamid))"
"                          Join Filter: (stats.playerid< stats_1.playerid)"
"                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 14299400"
"                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on stats  (cost=0.00..193042.83 rows=5958083 width=28) (actual time=0.025..550.519 rows=4766467 loops=3)"
"                          ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=193042.83..193042.83 rows=5958083 width=26) (actual time=1795.540..1795.541 rows=4766467 loops=3)"
"                                Buckets: 16777216  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1015264kB"
"                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on stats stats_1  (cost=0.00..193042.83 rows=5958083 width=26) (actual time=0.247..677.131 rows=4766467 loops=3)"
"Planning Time: 0.250 ms"
"Execution Time: 12766.802 ms"
```

| Node Type | Count | Time spent | % of query |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aggregate | 2 | 4609.959 ms | 36.97% |
| Gather | 1 | 245.895 ms | 1.98% |
| Hash | 1 | 1648.838 ms | 13.23% |
| Hash Inner Join | 1 | 5551.097 ms | 44.52% |
| Seq Scan | 2 | 413.862 ms | 3.32% |

[image]

**Output Query Plan using EXPLAIN ANALYZE w/ CTE (~3m 20s)**:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
with cte as  (
    SELECT 
      matchId, 
      teamId, 
      championId, 
      teamPosition, 
      win 
    FROM 
      stats
  )
SELECT 
  s1.championId, 
  s1.teamPosition, 
  s2.championId, 
  s2.teamPosition, 
  AVG(s1.win), 
  COUNT(s1.championId) 
FROM cte
  as s1 FULL 
  JOIN cte as s2 ON s1.matchId = s2.matchId 
  AND s1.teamId = s2.teamId 
WHERE 
  s1.championId < s2.championId 
GROUP BY 
  s1.championId, 
  s1.teamPosition, 
  s2.championId, 
  s2.teamPosition
```

.

```
"HashAggregate  (cost=327573056.36..387509157.98 rows=1600000000 width=108) (actual time=199782.693..199881.636 rows=119692 loops=1)"
"  Group Key: s1.playerId, s1.teamposition, s2.playerId, s2.teamposition"
"  Planned Partitions: 512  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 122905kB"
"  CTE cte"
"    ->  Seq Scan on stats  (cost=0.00..276456.00 rows=14299400 width=28) (actual time=0.058..2016.167 rows=14299400 loops=1)"
"  ->  Merge Join  (cost=5534867.92..107914282.10 rows=1703940336 width=70) (actual time=150767.875..184300.397 rows=28598800 loops=1)"
"        Merge Cond: (((s1.matchid)::text = (s2.matchid)::text) AND (s1.teamid = s2.teamid))"
"        Join Filter: (s1.playerId< s2.playerId)"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 42898200"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=2767433.96..2803182.46 rows=14299400 width=100) (actual time=76168.147..81518.033 rows=14299400 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: s1.matchid, s1.teamid"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 554216kB"
"              ->  CTE Scan on cte s1  (cost=0.00..285988.00 rows=14299400 width=100) (actual time=0.062..6437.573 rows=14299400 loops=1)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=2767433.96..2838930.96 rows=14299400 width=98) (actual time=74599.713..82923.371 rows=71496996 loops=1)"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=2767433.96..2803182.46 rows=14299400 width=98) (actual time=74599.707..79643.082 rows=14299400 loops=1)"
"                    Sort Key: s2.matchid, s2.teamid"
"                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 517872kB"
"                    ->  CTE Scan on cte s2  (cost=0.00..285988.00 rows=14299400 width=98) (actual time=0.030..1597.666 rows=14299400 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.108 ms"
"Execution Time: 200067.776 ms"
```

| Node Type | Count | Time spent | % of query |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Aggregate | 1 | 13516.971 ms | 6.45% |
| CTE Scan | 2 | 9575.973 ms | 4.57% |
| Materialize | 1 | 3488.241 ms | 1.67% |
| Merge Inner Join | 1 | 21367.373 ms | 10.2% |
| Merge Inner Join | 1 | 21367.373 ms | 10.2% |
| Seq Scan | 1 | 2684.041 ms | 1.29% |
| Sort | 2 | 159019.036 ms | 75.85% |

Comment: Your `FROM stats` query looks like it should be a named CTE, as it looks like you're repeating the query.

Comment: Correct I used to use a CTE but it increased the runtime to minutes rather than seconds I wasn't able to understand why

Comment: On a side note: If you want your result sorted, add an `ORDER BY` clause. `GROUP BY` doesn't guarantee a sorted result.

Comment: @Jack If using a CTE alters performance, then (ideally...) it indicates that the query's semantics are different, which in-turn suggests there might be a bug in your query - can you share your CTE version and the plan Oracle used with it? I'm curious...

Comment: i don't understabnd your query, can you provide a wanted result from your sample data

Comment: @Dai Sorry for the delay, updated with my CTE query and the execution plan. Maybe I made a mistake in the query but it took way longer 3min (w/ CTE) vs 14s (W/o CTE)

Comment: That being said when only using the dummy n=1 example, its faster with the CTE

Comment: Do you really need a `FULL JOIN`? I do not see a difference in results when changing that to an [INNER] JOIN.  (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/5iuptdHJ )

Comment: Yeah doesn't seem like it, I think inner is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? I'm not sure will it help or not.

```
SELECT 
  s1.playerId, 
  s1.teamPosition, 
  s2.playerId, 
  s2.teamPosition, 
  AVG(s1.win), 
  COUNT(s1.playerId) 
FROM stats s1
FULL JOIN stats s2
  ON s1.matchId = s2.matchId AND s1.teamId = s2.teamId 
WHERE 
  s1.playerId < s2.playerId 
GROUP BY 
  s1.playerId, 
  s1.teamPosition, 
  s2.playerId, 
  s2.teamPosition;
```

make sure you have db indexes on `stats.teamId` and `stats.matchId`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_stats_match_team ON stats(matchId, teamId);
```

update. 
second version:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_stats_match_team_player ON stats(matchId, teamId, playerId);

SELECT 
  s1.playerId, 
  s1.teamPosition, 
  s2.playerId, 
  s2.teamPosition, 
  AVG(s1.win), 
  COUNT(s1.playerId) 
FROM stats s1
INNER JOIN stats s2
  ON s1.matchId = s2.matchId 
  AND s1.teamId = s2.teamId 
  AND s1.playerId < s2.playerId 
GROUP BY 
  s1.playerId, 
  s1.teamPosition, 
  s2.playerId, 
  s2.teamPosition;
```

Comment: @Jack does it make sense?

Comment: Yes this makes sense. The subqueries in the original query are not needed and just make the query less readable. The index can help speed up the join. After all, though, there is another join condition on the playerid, so it may make sense to add this column at the end of the index, but the difference in speed, if any, won't be great, I guess. The condition can be moved from `WHERE`to `ON`, but this would just be for readability and is left to personal preference.

Comment: Might help to know that the full stats table includes an additional 3 columns (which are not used) matchLength, Possession_X, and Possession Y. Your query above took me 1m 30s rather than the 13s before.

Comment: @Jack I got you. Can you check second option? I changed `full join` to `inner join`

Comment: I guess that won't make a difference, because the `WHERE` clause turned the outer join into an inner join implicitly already. But its more readable to make this explicit by using an inner join right away.

Comment: @BaktybekBaiserkeev Your Second update is better but remains the same time as the original query, index doesn't seem to get used.